# Batch script, call cmd on servers

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to call x.cmd from many servers in a list and basically x.cmd will return a log file so I will copy the output log files into a new folder.
the structure in that list is:
server name&folder path of the x.cmd on thet server&output folder name that I will create

when I run the script below, it doesn't return any error and return value is 0. but x.cmd just doesn't do anything when I check on the actual server. x.cmd working fine once I run it manually.

Please if possible point me out the mistake of my script. my other concern is the folder path being too long(but it is within the limits of Microsoft if I am right).  :)  Thanks for your time.

```
@echo on

cd /d %~dp0

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set serverList=List.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3* delims=&" %%A in ("%serverList%") DO (

        set remoteCmd=x.cmd
        wmic /node:%%A process call create "%%B\remoteCmd"
        pause
        robocopy %%B\logs Output\%%C /e
)
endlocal
Pause
```

JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're not actually calling `x.cmd` on the remote servers, since the variable isn't substituted in the `wmic` call. Move the definition of `remoteCmd` out of the loop and enclose `remoteCmd` in the `wmic` call in percent signs:

```
set serverList=List.txt
set remoteCmd=x.cmd    
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3* delims=&" %%A in ("%serverList%") DO (
        wmic /node:%%A process call create "%%B\%remoteCmd%"
        pause
        robocopy %%B\logs Output\%%C /e
)
```

**Update 1:** Since you're getting a response on the shell with a `processID` and `Error level=0`, it's fairly safe to say that `x.cmd` was in fact started on the remote server. The fact that the logfile does not turn up in the same directory where `x.cmd` resides in, is very probably because the logfile is not given an absolute path in `x.cmd`. That means it will be created in the directory on the remote machine where the `cmd.exe` is located, which is executing `x.cmd`. In most systems this will be `%WINDIR%\system32`, i.e. `c:\windows\system32`.

**Update 2:** If modifying `x.cmd` is no option, then you need to change the path to it's directory before calling it. You can do it like this:

```
wmic /node:%%A process call create "cmd /c cd /d %%B & x.cmd"
```

*Note:* The `cd /d` allows you to change directories even across different drives.

**Update 3:** Since there are spaces in the directory names you'll need to enclose them with quotes - which will have to be escaped, since there already outer quotes enclosing the whole remote command. So that means:

```
wmic /node:%%A process call create "cmd /c \"cd /d %%B\" & x.cmd"
```

*Note:* A possible alternative to the inner quotes would be to use 8.3-filenames of the involved directories. You can view those with `dir /x` on the command line.

Comment: i have changed it exact the same way but still nothing happening. a cmd window poped out for a sec, assuming something happening but nothing in the output log. :(

Comment: Hm, I assume you're not seeing any helpful error message on the command-line? Something like "Access denied" or "Invalid global parameter"?

Comment: I am not seeing anything, its weird, looks like running successfully cuz it shows processID and Error level=0, but yeah even I tried a local server but still the same. drive me nuts.

Comment: In `x.cmd`, you're obviously specifying the output filename `logs` somewhere. Try making that an _absolute_ path, like `c:\mydir\logs`. In my tests this was necessary for anyfile to be written on the remote system.

Comment: Just found out that the files were created in `%WINDIR%\System32` when using a relative path/filename.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will try tomorrow when I get back in the office. thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Thanks thats exactly the problem zb226, for x.cmd, it doesn't know the path if I call it remotely. if i add 'cd /d %~dp0' in x.cmd then my script above works perfectly!. but the problem is i am not allowed to touch x.cmd. is there any other way to do with my script. searched a bit, others are talking about adding 'cmd /d' in front of   %%B\%remoteCmd% but no luck for me.

Comment: Tried some more and this did it on my end: `...process call create "cmd /c cd /d PATH_TO_X_CMD & PATH_TO_X_CMD\x.cmd"`.

Comment: HI ZB226 if the path has whitespaces, by adding double quotes "cmd /c cd /d "PATH_TO_X_CMD" & "PATH_TO_X_CMD"\x.cmd" doesn't work. any recommendation?

Comment: Yes, you need to escape each of the inner double quotes with a backslash. Btw, it seems you can omit the second `PATH_TO_X_CMD` as I just ran `...process call create "cmd /c cd /d \"c:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\Sample Playlists\" & x.cmd"` successfully, with the output appearing in the same directory. If you don't mind I would like to sum up all these findings in your answer and my question, because I think there's some valuable lessons learned here and as it is now, it's not exactly good readable, because it's all in the comments.

Comment: Yes could you please just update the answer above please. Much Appreciated!

Comment: just tried wmic /node:%%A process call create "cmd /c cd /d \"%%B" & x.cmd", doesn't work. error as invalid format. maybe I miss something, waiting for your update in the actual answer. :)

Comment: The extensive edit will have to wait a bit I'm afraid ... for now - it seems like you forgot to escape the inner closing quote: `\"%%B\"`. An alternative workaround that came to mind is using the old 8.3 directory names and thus not bothering with the whole spaces-in-directory-names issue. You can view those on the console by executing `dir /x` (e.g. `c:\Program Files` usually becomes `c:\progra~1`).

Comment: Its all working. script working like an angle! thanks so much zb226!!